# How to mock get api data in protractor e2e tests?

Tags: mocking, protractor, e2e-testing

Is there any way to mock the data coming from a API in protractor e2e test? For eg: there is a get api on my page which sometimes fails and hence my all e2e tests for that page fails. So I want to mock this get api and gives a certain data irrespective of the data coming from API.
This can be done in unit test using spyOn. Not sure of E2e.

#UPDATE

For e2e I am using protractor-http-mock as mentioned below:-

In e2e-spec.ts file

```
var mock = require('protractor-http-mock');

beforeEach(function(){
        mock([{
            request: {
                path: '/listReports',
                method: 'GET'
            },
            response: {
                status: 200
            }
        }]);
    });

afterEach(function(){
        mock.teardown();
    });
```

But nothing sort of working, still tc's are failing.

Comment: This literally defeats the entire purpose of e2e tests. A better approach would be to figure out why your api call is failing and fix that.

Comment: can you please see my update code?